# Can VMware Player run on an Acer A7 running Chrubuntu?

Tags: linux, vmware

Does anyone know if VMware Player can run on an Acer A7 running Chrubuntu?

(The kernel module updater is looking for files and maybe I just don't know the path?)

Answer (score 2):

VMware Player can run on any Linux distribution.
There are distribution-related packages but there are also "generic packages", often including a `.sh` file, which after being given executable permission flags can be run by doing `./packagename.sh` with root privileges.

In Ubuntu-derived distros, however, there is another method, which involves a little bit of command line operations.

The steps needed are as follows:

> 1. Install required packages build-essential and linux-headers:
>    `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
> 2. Download the latest VMware player e.g. VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.i386.bundle (download the bundle version,
>      not the rpm one) and run it as root using gksudo. You'll get a
>      graphical installer that installs VMware player for you.
>    `gksudo
>      bash ./Downloads/VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.i386.bundle`
> 3. Note: this assumes the location of your Downloads folder is home/Downloads. If nothing appears, you may need to make the file
>      executable. You can do so with this command:
>    `chmod +x
>      ./Downloads/VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.i386.bundle`
>
> (again, with the assumption of your Downloads folder location). After
>   completion, VMware player is installed and should show up in the menu
>   under Applications → System Tools → VMware Player. As well, you may
>   notice that when trying to create a new virtual machine, vmware will
>   complain on the terminal output that:
>
> VMware Player is installed, but it has not been (correctly) configured
>   for your running kernel. To (re-)configure it, your system
>   administrator must find and run "vmware-config.pl". For more
>   information, please see the VMware Player documentation.
>
> vmware-config.pl is not present anymore in the latest vmware-player
>   versions (seems to have been superseded by vmware-modconfig). If you
>   have this problem you may instead need to check if you have a
>   /etc/vmware/not_configured file and, if so, delete it.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player